# Asciimatics Keyboard Input

Tags: python, user-interface, asciimatics

I just started using the asciimatics library, and I want it to take keyboard input. My code thus far is:

```
from asciimatics import *
import time

def demo(screen):
    while True:
        x = screen.get_event()
        if x:
            screen.print_at(str(x), 0, 0)
            screen.refresh()

Screen.wrapper(demo)
```

But when i, say, try to type "e" it gives me this:

```
KeyboardEvent: 101) 0
```

It collects these random numbers on keyboard and mouse events. (I only want keyboard events).

I want it to record keyboard input similar to **input**.
Edit: does it need to be something "chr"?

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/asciimatics.html#asciimatics.screen.Screen.get_event), `get_event` returns `Events`.  To get the string value of the key pressed, use `chr(x.key_code)` if for any `KeyboardEvent`.